# Is it necessary to set multiple primary shards for very big data when elasticsearch is on a single server?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I installed elasticsearch in a single server. I want to know is it necessary to set `num_of_shards` greater than 1 when the data is very large?  I assume if I set `num_of_shards` greater than 1 but those shards are in a single disk. when I search something and the quest are assign to those shard. The performance may be lower than this scenario setting `num_of_shards` equal to 1, is there any problem with my view?

Temporarily, I only have one server available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underneath each shard is a complete Lucene index and for elasticsearch to serve request it will need to query each shard sequentially. Although the performance effect would be mitigated if the SSD is used but still it is a performance hit. Usually the number of shards are kept to be more than the nodes in cluster because later if you want to increase the number of shards you would require to re-index the entire data which is not feasible in some cases. [This](https://cpratt.co/how-many-shards-should-elasticsearch-indexes-have/) article explains this well.

Answer (score 0):

I would do one shard + one replica ( different drive may be), There may be some reasons to do multiple shards based on your usage and data distribution  - but for most part one shard should be fine.

Newer versions of ES support [dynamic resharding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-split-index.html) in case you add more servers/data in future.